# Page encoding and Jquery-Ui (ajax tabs)

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am developing a web application and I'm forced to use:

```
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

as a character encoding. I'm trying to use Jquery-ui to make some beautified tabs, but I cannot manage to get the correct encoding.

I tried this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ ajaxOptions: { contentType: "text/html; charset=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" } });
```

but with no luck. Does anybody have any clue on this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` is the collation for 1251 codepage (CP1 - 1251, CI - case insensitive, AS - accent sensitive). So as your content type you should use

```
"text/html; charset=windows-1252"
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct encoding (the SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS worked as well for the "normal" pages).
The problem still remains with jquery tabs thought.